# How to mock a private function in android test with MockK?

Tags: kotlin, android-testing, mockk

I can't seem to mock private functions in android tests. I'm also using the all-open plugin for pre-P testing. On non-android tests it runs with no problems. I figured it should work on android too, because it's marked on MockK-android. Is this not implemented or am I missing something obvious?

```
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.8.7"

@OpenForTesting
class A {
    fun publicFun() = privateFun()
    private fun privateFun() {}
    protected fun protectedFun() {}
}

@Test
fun privateFunctionMock() {
    val spy = spyk<A>()
    val mock = mockk<A>()
    val a = A()

    val functions = a::class.functions // size -> 6
    val spyFunctions = spy::class.functions // size -> 5
    val mockFunctions = mock::class.functions // size -> 5

    every { spy["privateFun"]() } returns Unit

    a.publicFun()
}
```

Fails with Exception, because the private function is missing.
**io.mockk.MockKException: can't find function privateFun() for dynamic call**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclassing is employed to create mocks and spies for pre-P android instrumented tests. That means basically private methods are skipped because it is not possible to inherit them. That way counters are not counting private methods.

Comment: Thanks for this quick response. Is it a mistake on the https://mockk.io/ANDROID.html, marking "private function mocking" on pre-P android as supported? Thanks for MockK!

Answer (score -3):

```
InternalPlatformDsl.dynamicSet(autoBannerViewPagerMock, "mBannerList", list)
every { autoBannerViewPagerMock.invoke("loadCoverImage") withArguments listOf(any<Int>(), any<Int>(), any<ImageView>(), any<stMetaBanner>()) } returns Unit
```

Comment: How does it answer the original question?